How to host Angular Application to work on domain root while keeping in a separate folder in webapps directory in tomcat
I have bought a VPS server and installed tomcat 10. I want to run angular app on domain root like: www.example.com and not www.example.com/myapp. I also want to keep the angular app to deploy in a separate folder (webapps/myapp) rather than deploying files to webapps directly.

Simply deploy your app to webapps/ROOT instead of webapps/myapp. ROOT (in all capital letters) is the key name for tomcat's app answering on /, all other directory names stand for webapps with the verbatim same name.

There are couple of things to consider. First we need to change the context path for tomcat to our application. for that edit the server.xml file in tomcat and add this to Host node:
<Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/app_name" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>

also add the RewriteValve in the same Host node:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

Now we need to rewrite traffic to our app, create a rewrite.config file in this location:
/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost

Then add the following content inside:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /app_name/index.html [L]

Finally when building the app from angular, just do "ng build"
